# How to install gevent on an updated Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: python, ubuntu-14.04, gevent

Lately when I try to install `gevent` 1.0.2 I get the following error:

```
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DLIBEV_EMBED=1 -DEV_COMMON= -DEV_CLEANUP_ENABLE=0 -DEV_EMBED_ENABLE=0 -DEV_PERIODIC_ENABLE=0 -Ibuild/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libev -Ilibev -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c gevent/gevent.corecext.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/gevent/gevent.corecext.o

In file included from gevent/libev.h:2:0,
                 from gevent/gevent.corecext.c:249:
libev/ev.c:45:22: fatal error: config.h: Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type
 #  include "config.h"
                      ^

compilation terminated.
error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

What am I missing?  No matter if I install `libev-dev` or not it keeps stoping at the same error.

Comment: I'm facing the same problem.  More details:  Compilation only fails with `pip` or `easy_install`, if I get the source code and run `python setup.py install` it works.  However I need that `easy_install` be able to install this since this is needed for buildout based builds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checking the TMPDIR does not have the "noexec" flag.

Alternatively you may run pip with `TMPDIR=/home/$USER/tmp pip install gevent`.